# Bigquery datasets event table

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on two projects and was fetching some data from the events table for the last twelve months for both projects.

But in one of them I can't go back more than 144 days, I guess this is the number in parentheses next to the events_**(144)**.

What I'm asking, is there some way of increasing how many days the data is collected in the events table, or is it a size limitation?

Comment: Where are these events table from? When you mean you can not go back more than 144 , do you get any error ?

Comment: I don't get any errors just the 144 days even if I ask for a longer time period. But I found the answer! We simply implemented Bigquery for the project 144 days ago, But thanks for your engagement.